# My Custom Meta Box Won't Save

Tags: wordpress, meta

I have created a custom post type and also added some meta boxes.  I am able to display the custom post type on the front end as well as built in elements such as post title and featured image.  When saving information in my meta box it clears the fields when I save the post.  Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'fellowship_church_information' );
function fellowship_church_information() {
add_meta_box( 
    'fellowship_church_information',                    // Unique ID
    __( 'Church Information', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),  // Title
    'fellowship_church_information_content',            // Callback function
    'fellowship',                                       // Admin page (or post type)
    'normal',                                           // Context
    'default'                                           // Priority
);
}

function fellowship_church_information_content( $post ) {
echo '<div class="fellowship-church-information-form">

    <label for="church_name">Church Name: </label> <input type="text" id="church_name" name="church_name" placeholder="" /> <br />

    <label for="church_address">Church Address: </label> <input type="text" id="church_address" name="church_address" placeholder="" /> <br />

    <label for="church_city">Church City: </label> <input type="text" id="church_city" name="church_city" placeholder="" />

    <label for="church_state">Church State: </label> 
    <select id="church_state" name="church_state" placeholder="">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

    <label for="church_zip">Church Zip: </label> <input type="text" id="church_zip" name="church_zip" placeholder="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="fellowship_noncename" id="fellowship_noncename" value="' . wp_create_nonce( 'fellowship-nonce' ) . '" />
    </div>


    ';
}


//  SAVING THE INFORMATION TO THE DATABASE

add_action( 'save_post', 'fellowship_church_information_save', 10, 6 );
function fellowship_church_information_save( $post_id ) {

  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
  return;

  if ( 'fellowship' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
    return;
  } else {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return;
  }
  if (isset($_POST['fellowship_noncename'])){
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['fellowship_noncename'], 'fellowship-nonce' ) )
        return;
  }else{
      return;
  }
  $fellowship_church_information = $_POST['fellowship_church_information'];
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'fellowship_church_information', $_POST['fellowship_church_information'] );
}




//  ADD SHORTCODE -- [fellowships]
function fellowships_func( $atts ){

//  DISPLAYING THE INFORMATION
$queryFellowship = array(
      'post_type' => 'fellowship',
    );

$fellowships = new WP_Query( $queryFellowship );
    if( $fellowships->have_posts() ) {
      while( $fellowships->have_posts() ) {
        $fellowships->the_post();
        echo '<h1>' . the_title() . '</h1>';
        echo '<div class="fellowships-content">';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
        }
        the_content();
        get_metadata();
        $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );
        echo $meta;
        echo '</div>';
      }
    }
    else {
      echo '<h2 class="no-fellowships">There are currently no upcoming Alumni &amp; Friends Fellowships.</h2>';
    }

}
add_shortcode( 'fellowships', 'fellowships_func' );
```

Again, I am able to display the title and the featured image but not the custom meta.

Comment: `$_POST['reviews_noncename']` is a mistake, the line should read`$_POST['fellowship_noncename]`

Comment: Thank you @David - I should have caught that.  However, I updated it in my file and I still am having the same results..

Comment: use `exit` instead of return in your validation code to double check where the issue is (echo something to identify before exit). Also `$_POST['fellowship_church_information']` doesn't exist you need to collect each `$_POST` field individually, i.e. `$name=$_POST['chruch_name']` etc

Comment: @David I dropped this for a while due to other projects.  Thanks for the advice!  Collecting each $_POST field was what I needed to do.  It all works now.